# Cannot execute binary file when not logged in as su

Tags: linux, terminal

I am playing around with Linux, and am starting out with using the terminal. I am trying to create folders on the root of the filesystem, which my regular user does not have permissions to do.

When running `su root mkdir u01`; I am prompted for credentials, and then Terminal returns the error "Cannot execute binary file"

If I run `su root` and then `mkdir u01`, the command works fine.

Any ideas?

I am on Oracle Linux 6.5

Comment: maybe the user who you try to execute the command through hasn't sufficient credentials to do so !

Comment: What is your default shell for root? What is the output of `locate mkdir`?  I am asking because in one case you might be trying to run a binary called mkdir and in the su case you might be using a shell internal command.

Comment: Not asked, but consider creating these folders on /usr/local/. That is probably a local partition which should remain intact if you ever need to reinstall the OS. See [man hier](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier)

Comment: I'm running a VM test environment, regularly snapshotted, so screwing up is no biggie.

Using /u01 /u02 etc is the norm within Oracle systems, which is why I needed to create that folder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is your call to `su`.

The correct syntax for executing a command as another user is:

```
su [username] -c "[command]"
```

Note the quotes around the command; its important to keep the other arguments to the command get executed properly.

Comment: When I try that, I hit a new roadblock: terminal returns mkdir: missing operand. The command I run is: su root -c mkdir u03

Comment: @razumny You should type **su root -c 'mkdir u03'** The apostrophes are part of the command, you must type them.

Comment: Yes, the quotes are important. I'll update my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, a "normal" user shouldn't be allowed to create files or folders in the root of the filesystem.  Allowing it leads to all manner of security issues.

When you run "su root mkdir u01", your system is asking you for the root password.  What you probably should be running is "sudo mkdir u01" which will ask you for your normal user password.  Note that this assumes that sudo is properly configured to allow this.

Comment: Why would you -1 my answer.  I'd assumed that you'd already read the man page for su and saw the "-c" switch.  My answer is correct.  If it's not the one that you like, a more polite response would have been to leave it at 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `sudo` properly configured, this is proper way to create that directory:

```
sudo mkdir u01
```

If sudo does not work for some reason (or not even installed - unlikely, but possible), you can use `su` with command parameter `-c`, like this:

```
su -c "mkdir u01"
```

(note that command must be quoted to be passed properly to `su`).

Important difference between using `sudo` vs `su`: when prompted for password, `sudo` needs your user account password, but `su` needs root account password. On many Linux distros (notably Ubuntu/Debian family) root account password may not even be ever assigned, so `su` may fail (unless you assign password to root account beforehand).